# Java padding image

Tags: java, image-processing, image-editing

I am working on creating an online image editing tool.Looking for some refernce how can I add an image with white space on right side.For example  see this image [image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Presumably, you want to create a new image from an existing image, where the new image has white space on the left and right?

Suppose the unpadded image was a BufferedImage and is called 'image'.  Suppose the amount of whitespace you want on each side is 'w'.  What you want to do is create a new BufferedImage wider than the original, then paint the entire thing white, and finally draw the smaller image on top of it:

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth() + 2 * w, image.getHeight(), image.getType());

Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth() + 2 * w, image.getHeight());
g.drawImage(image, w, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes upon a similar problem, I would definitively recommend [imgScalr](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr). You can add padding with literally one line `imageSource= Scalr.pad(imageSource,pad,Color.White);`.

Comment: Thank you for the great tip!

Comment: imgScalr seems to be a nice library, but I do not see any way to pad only 2 borders (i.e., left-right side); padding is always added to all 4 borders. Of course, you can crop afterwards to remove the padding from top-bottom borders, but this is not very clean and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `BufferedImage` object of the right size; use `Graphics.fillRect()` to paint it white; draw the image into the top-left corner with `drawImage()`; then save your new image.